# Word or Report file show on iframe in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to show a word file or any report file in asp.net mvc project?

```
public FileStreamResult GetPDF() 
 {
    FileStream fs =   new             

   FileStream(Server.MapPath(@"~/File/SegmentAdd.txt"),
   FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
    return File(fs, "application/pdf");
}



 <iframe src="@Url.Action("GetPDF")"  width="90%" height="90%"></iframe>
```